# TideSDK - Set child window always to topMost of main window

Tags: javascript, tidesdk

I have a project that consists in creating an app that works on top of other apps. My app stays always on top and allows transparency for interaction with apps bellow. All is going ok, I've applied topMost (true) to the app and its ok.

Because I ways having problems with getting window dialogs (alert but not prompt nor confirm) to stay on top and void interaction with my main window until it gets closed - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tidesdk/yYkEcC6X5y0 - I had to create my own dialog windows. I managed to get this one going by creating a child window, setting its property topMost to true and always refocusing the dialog whenever there was an atemp to activate/focus main window.

My problem comes when another window needs to be created to act like a Photoshop   floating tools window. This window looses its focus and gets beneath main window during itereaction with main app and dialogs. I need this window to always stay on top of main window and under dialog tools so that  UX gets correct.

I've managed to get the window to stay on top, but I'm playing arround with focus and unfocus for all windows and it is getting messy.

Does anyone no how can I get to set the order from a main window and all its child windows?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this one quickly, so here it is:

When creating all windows (main, tools and dialogs) I only use the topMost param property on method createWindow
( https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-doc/tree/master/source/guides/getting_started#window-elements ).

On main window I only use the tiapp.xml properties
(https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-doc/tree/master/source/guides/getting_started#tiappxml-configuration).

It is only with the tools window that I invoke method setTopMost (true) at window init (one time execution). This way the window will always  stay on top of all.

Finally for the dialogs I force focus whenever user tries to interact with tools or main window.

so order goes like this (top to bottom)

- dialog      ( xml property topMost and always forcing focus )
- tools        ( xml property topMost and setTopMost method on init )
- window  ( xml property topMost )

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the previous solution wasn't correctly tested. Main app did not have the tiapp.xml defining top-most to true. So I guess I need to take a deeper look into this issue

:(